# Combined comparison Operator (<=>) and null coalescing operator (??)

Tags: php, php-7

Details about combined comparison operator (<=>) and null coalescing operator (??)

Comment: [`<=>`](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/combined-comparison-operator), [`??`](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary), [comparison operators](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/combined-comparison-operator)

Comment: Have you thought about reading the documentation?

Comment: @vascowhite Yes, but documentation has only some brief information not detail.

Comment: Answer is found here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666256/null-coalesce-operator-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combined comparison operator return -1, 0, or 1, depending on which is greater than the other:

```
if ($x <=> $y == -1) {
    echo '$x < $y';
} elseif ($x <=> $y == 1) {
    echo '$x > $y';
} else {
    echo '$x == $y';
}
```

The null coalescing operator is similar to doing `$x ?: $y`, but is checking for `null` instead of false-y:

```
$x = null;
$y = 'hello';
echo $x ?? $y; //hello
echo $x ?: $y; //hello
$x = 0;
$y = 1;
echo $x ?? $y; //0;
echo $x ?: $y; //1
```

Comment: `??` is more sophisticated than that. It also does `isset()`.

Comment: and I believe it does not throw a notice if the variable is not defined, like empty()