# What is the 'Null coalesce' (??) operator used for?

Tags: php, coding-style, operators, php-7

With the release of a new PHP version, PHP 7, new features are introduced. among these new features is an operator I am not familiar with. The `Null coalesce operator`.

What is this operator and what are some good use cases?

Comment: From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/fr/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op): "*The null coalesce operator (??) has been added as syntactic sugar for the common case of needing to use a ternary in conjunction with isset(). It returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise it returns its second operand.*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it to init a variable that might be null

> The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator. It returns the
>   left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the
>   right hand operand.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ms173224.aspx

(not dependent on language)

Use case

You can write

```
$rabbits;

$rabbits = count($somearray);

if ($rabbits == null) {
    $rabbits = 0;
}
```

You can use the shorter notation

```
$rabbits = $rabbits ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the PHP Manual:

> The null coalesce operator (??) has been added as syntactic sugar for the common case of needing to use a ternary in conjunction with isset(). It returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise it returns its second operand.

```
// Fetches the value of $_GET['user'] and returns 'nobody'
// if it does not exist.
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? 'nobody';
// This is equivalent to:
$username = isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : 'nobody';

// Coalesces can be chained: this will return the first
// defined value out of $_GET['user'], $_POST['user'], and
// 'nobody'.
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? $_POST['user'] ?? 'nobody';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? 'nobody';
```

is same as

`$username = isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : 'nobody';`

?? is ternary shorthand